# Issue in reading csv file from spring configuration file

Tags: spring

I have mentioned csv file in *job.quartz.xml*  like below.

```
<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <!-- Read a csv file -->
        <property name="resource" value="classpath*:csv/input/report.csv" />
```

And I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): class path resource [classpath*:csv/input/report.csv]
```

[image]

Comment: The error suggests that the file is not in the classpath. At what location is the file present ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `classpath*` with `classpath`